# Determining number of unique prescriptions per period from long dataset with overlap

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in Stata that looks something like that shown below. I would like to count how many *unique* prescriptions each individual is taking per period. The start and end periods are inclusive (i.e. the prescription would be counted as being taken for both these periods):

```
| Person | Prescription | Start period | End period |
|--------|--------------|--------------|------------|
| 1      | A            | 1            | 2          |
| 1      | A            | 2            | 3          |
| 1      | A            | 3            | 4          |
| 1      | B            | 2            | 3          |
| 1      | B            | 4            | 5          |
| 1      | C            | 2            | 4          |
| 1      | C            | 5            | 6          |
| 2      | A            | 2            | 3          |
| 2      | A            | 3            | 4          |
| 2      | B            | 1            | 2          |
| 2      | B            | 2            | 3          |
| 2      | C            | 2            | 3          |
| 2      | C            | 3            | 4          |
| 2      | C            | 5            | 6          |
```

This is what the final dataset would look like in this case:

```
| Person | Period | Unique Prescriptions |
|--------|--------|----------------------|
| 1      | 1      | 1                    |
| 1      | 2      | 3                    |
| 1      | 3      | 3                    |
| 1      | 4      | 3                    |
| 1      | 5      | 2                    |
| 1      | 6      | 1                    |
| 2      | 1      | 1                    |
| 2      | 2      | 3                    |
| 2      | 3      | 3                    |
| 2      | 4      | 2                    |
| 2      | 5      | 1                    |
| 2      | 6      | 1                    |
```

An additional note is that prescriptions should not be double-counted within a certain period (for instance, prescription A should be counted only once in period 2 for person 1 even though there is an overlap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the tag wiki for advice on how to give examples of Stata data. Your example is clear but needs some surgery before it can be used as Stata code.

See [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800800408) where it is argued that the term *unique* should be avoided when the issue is counting *distinct* values.

See also [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1301300116) on what to do with paired dates.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte Person str1 Prescription byte(Start_Period End_Period)
1 "A" 1 2
1 "A" 2 3
1 "A" 3 4
1 "B" 2 3
1 "B" 4 5
1 "C" 2 4
1 "C" 5 6
2 "A" 2 3
2 "A" 3 4
2 "B" 1 2
2 "B" 2 3
2 "C" 2 3
2 "C" 3 4
2 "C" 5 6
end

gen long obsno = _n
expand End_Period - Start_Period + 1 
bysort obsno : gen Period = Start_Period + _n - 1
drop Start_Period End_Period obsno 
duplicates drop 
sort Person Period 
contract Person Period, freq(Distinct)

list, sepby(Person)

     +----------------------------+
     | Person   Period   Distinct |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |      1        1          1 |
  2. |      1        2          3 |
  3. |      1        3          3 |
  4. |      1        4          3 |
  5. |      1        5          2 |
  6. |      1        6          1 |
     |----------------------------|
  7. |      2        1          1 |
  8. |      2        2          3 |
  9. |      2        3          3 |
 10. |      2        4          2 |
 11. |      2        5          1 |
 12. |      2        6          1 |
     +----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Appreciate your ingenuity, as always!